# Uncaught ReferenceError: selectInput is not defined at HTMLLIElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, uncaught-reference-error

I have this function that is responsible for showing all possible title that are inside my database, and I keep having problem with my function selectInput.

The selectInput function is responsible for putting the list that was clicked by the user inside the inputBox.

```js
function displayAllTitles(availableKeywords, availableKeyTitle) {

  const resultsBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
  const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");

  inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
    let result = [];
    let input = inputBox.value;

    if (input.length) {
      result = availableKeywords.filter((keyword) => {
        return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
      });
      console.log(result);
    }
    display(result);
  }

  function display(result) {
    const content = result.map((list) => {
      return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
    });
    resultsBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
  }

  function selectInput(list) {
    inputBox.value = list.innerHTML;
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

and I keep getting the error Uncaught ReferenceError: selectInput is not defined at HTMLLIElement.onclick, how do I fix this?

Here is my html file:

```
<div class="search-box">
  <div class="row">
    <input
     type="text"
     placeholder="Search"
     id="input-box"
     autocomplete="off"
    />
    <div class="result-box" id="result-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML content too

Comment: Also, how are you calling the various functions?

Comment: @ShriHariL I have updated my code above.

Comment: @DavidThomas I call them inside the function as well, because I need to pass a certain variable to each function.

Comment: Because the method is defined inside of a function and is not global. `selectInput` can not be used outside of `displayAllTitles`. The inline event listener is looking for it globally. If you can not make it global, then you need to attach the event a different way.

Comment: declare your functions globally don't nest them inside of each other, only use calls when nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selectInput` function is only visible to `displayAllTitles` function. So we cannot access it from the DOM. I think you can attach the function reference like below and append it to the DOM.

```js
function display(result) {

    const ul = document.createElement('ul');

    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = result[i];
        li.onclick = () => selectInput(result[i]);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
    resultsBox.appendChild(ul);
}
function selectInput(list) {
    inputBox.value = list;
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not passing any value to the selectInput function

Comment: Edited the code.. Try now

Comment: It passes the code now in the selectInput function but I get the undefined value when outputting the list in the inputBox, is something wrong with "inputBox.value = list.innerHTML;" ?

Comment: Thanks its working now, I change my 'inputBox.value=list.innerHTML' to  'inputBox.value=list' and it works fine.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, missed it. Updated the answer